# renderComponent in Angular ivy with extra component/directive declarations

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

Here is an example of render dynamic lazy component in ivy:

```
import { ɵrenderComponent as renderComponent, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <app-lazy></app-lazy>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(injector: Injector) {
    import('./lazy.component').then(({ LazyComponent }) => {
      renderComponent(LazyComponent, {
        injector,
        host: 'app-lazy'
      });
    });
  }
}
```

What should I do if we need use extra component/directive in `lazy.component`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### you need a custom decorator

```
import {
  Component,
  Type,
  ɵComponentDef as ComponentDef,
  ɵDirectiveDef as DirectiveDef,
  ɵPipeDef as PipeDef
} from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
@ComponentDeps({
   directives: [...], //***extra component/directive you want***
   pipes: [...] //***extra pipe, like: JsonPipe...***
})
export class LazyComponent{
 ...
}



export interface ComponentDepsConfig {
  directives?: Type<any>[];
  pipes?: Type<any>[];
}
function getDirectiveDef<T>(t: Type<T>): DirectiveDef<T> {
  if (t['ɵdir']) {
    return t['ɵdir'] as DirectiveDef<T>;
  }
  if (t['ɵcmp']) {
    return t['ɵcmp'] as ComponentDef<T>;
  }
  throw new Error('No Angular definition found for ' + t.name);
}
function getDirectiveDefs(types: Type<any>[]): DirectiveDef<any>[] {
  return types.map(t => getDirectiveDef(t));
}

function getPipeDef<T>(t: Type<T>): PipeDef<T> {
  if (t['ɵpipe']) {
    return t['ɵpipe'] as PipeDef<T>;
  }
  throw new Error('No Angular definition found for ' + t.name);
}

export function getPipeDefs(types: Type<any>[]): PipeDef<any>[] {
  return types.map(t => getPipeDef(t));
}
export function ComponentDeps(config: ComponentDepsConfig) {
  return (componentType: Type<any>) => {
    const def = componentType['ɵcmp'] || componentType['ngComponentDef'];
    // directives or components
    def.directiveDefs = [
      ...getDirectiveDefs(config.directives || [])
    ];
    // pipes
    def.pipeDefs = [
      ...getPipeDefs(config.pipes || [])
    ];
  };
}
```

Comment: How do we set component and pipe deps? Can you add `components` and `pipes` fields 
 in ComponentDepsConfig?

Comment: see https://github.com/xiaoxiangmoe/angular-ivy-decorator-error-demo.

If I add `HelloWorldComponent` in `declarations` of `AppModule`, it works well. But now, it can't works.

Comment: I fork your demo,you need add schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA] to app.module.ts to prevent template error,it works pretty well
[screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvQct.png)

Comment: Thank you very much. Where is docs for `ɵdir`, `ɵcmp ` and `ɵpipe `?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setScopeOnDeclaredComponents(moduleType: Type<any>, component: any) {
  const transitiveScopes = ɵtransitiveScopesFor(moduleType);
  const componentDef = component[ɵNG_COMP_DEF];
  if (!componentDef) {
    console.error('not define comp')
  }
  ɵpatchComponentDefWithScope(componentDef, transitiveScopes);
}
```